# Convergence on $\ell^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I have been working on this problem. Show the following are equivalent:

i. $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|x_n\|_p<\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n(j)=0$ for each $j\geq1$,

ii. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}x_n(j)y(j)=0$ for each $y\in\ell^q(\mathbb{N})$,

where $1<p<\infty$,$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, and $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$.

This is what I have done so far:

For $(i)\Rightarrow(ii)$, when $y=\{y(j)\}\in\ell^q(\mathbb{N})$, by Holder's inequality, we have $$\left|\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}x_n(j)y(j)\right|\leq\|x_n\|_p\|y\|_q\to0$$
since $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n(j)=0$. Unfortunately, I could not do the reverse implication but this was my attempt:

I tried to define a linear functional $T_n$ from $\ell^q(\mathbb{N})\to\mathbb{R}$ by defining it as $$T_n(y)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_n(j)y(j).$$
Then I tried to show that $\|T_n\|=\|x_n\|_p$ so that by appealing to the hypothesis I could show $(i)$ to be true. However, I failed to establish that $\|T_n\|=\|x_n\|_p$. I'd appreciate if anyone could give some guide on how to do this.

Comment: Well, first, your proof that (i) implies (ii) is wrong. The hypothesis does not imply that $||x_n||_p\to0$. (Consider $x_n=e_n$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you for the correction. i was so reckless. now i'm back to square one. is there a way to do it?

Comment: Hint for the easy direction: If $y\in \ell^q$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ so $\sum_{j=N}^\infty|y(j)|^q<\epsilon$. (This is one place where $p>1$ is used...)